# Telnet in IP and ports in file (1st column is IP and 2nd column PORT )

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have a file with IP, PORTS and descriptions:

```sh
$cat ip-ports.txt
10.86.16.135 389 Mobil-esy DNS 
10.86.16.137 88 Mobil-fix DNS 
10.86.16.134 3268 Mobil-izm DNS 
10.86.16.139 464 Mobil-kipr centrify
```

I want to telnet and desired output would be formatted as the following:

```sh
Mobil-esy DNS 10.86.16.135 389 port is OPEN 
Mobil-fix DNS 10.86.16.137 88  port is DOWN 
Mobil-izm DNS 10.86.16.134 3268 port is OPEN
Mobil-kipr centrify  10.86.16.139 464 is DOWN
```

My script is here:

```sh
$ cat stackstatus.sh 
ipports=/ansible/roles/basic/tasks/portstatus/ip-ports.txt
for i in cat $ipports;
do
ip=$(cat $ipports | awk '{print $1}')
port=$(cat $ipports | awk '{print $2}')
echo $ip "and " $port
if  echo quit | timeout --signal=9 5  telnet $ip $port < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Connected
    then
        echo $3" " $1 " " $2 port is open
    else
        echo $3" " $1 " " $2 port is DOWN
    fi
 done
```

There is something wrong,getting the following output. Can you assist in solving the issue?

```
$ sh stackstatus.sh 
10.86.16.135 10.86.16.137 10.86.16.134 10.86.16.139 and  389 88 3268 464
        port is DOWN
10.86.16.135 10.86.16.137 10.86.16.134 10.86.16.139 and  389 88 3268 464
        port is DOWN
```

Comment: Please read [how to read a file field by field in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). `echo quit | timeout --signal=9 5  telnet $ip $port ...` just `if nc -zv <host> <port>; then`. The quotes `"` are meant _for_ variables, not around them. Put all `$<antyhing>` inside `"` like `"$3 $1 $2"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions,nc is cool. But not existing by default. I'm trying to use this scripts for each new created vm. There migh not be netcat package.So I prefer go on by telnet.
Solved as follow:

```
ipports=/ansible/roles/basic/tasks/portstatus/ip-ports.txt
openports=/tmp/open-ports.txt
downports=/tmp/downports.tx
touch $ $openports; > $openports;
touch  $downports; > $downports;

while read ip port description; 
do  
echo quit | timeout --signal=9 5  telnet $ip $port < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Connected ; 
#nc -zv $ip $port
result1=$?
if [  "$result1" != 0 ]; then
  echo $description ' '  $port  ' port is DOWN for ' $ip
  echo $description ' ' $port "port is down for " $ip >> $downports
else
  echo $description ' '  $port ' port is OPEN for' $ip 
  echo $description ' '  $port "port is down for " $ip >> $openports
fi
done < $ipports
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample input:

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ cat ip-list.txt 
8.8.8.8      53 google DNS
10.86.16.135 389 Mobil-esy DNS 
10.86.16.137 88 Mobil-fix DNS 
10.86.16.134 3268 Mobil-izm DNS 
10.86.16.139 464 Mobil-kipr centrify
```

Script

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ cat check-con-stat.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read ip port name service; do
   (echo quit | timeout --signal=9 2 telnet "$ip" "$port" 2>/dev/null | grep -q Connected) && status="OPEN" || status="DOWN"
   echo "$name $service $ip $port $status"       
done < ip-list.txt
```

Execution

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ chmod +x check-con-stat.sh 
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ ./check-con-stat.sh 
google DNS 8.8.8.8 53 OPEN
Mobil-esy DNS 10.86.16.135 389 DOWN
Mobil-fix DNS 10.86.16.137 88 DOWN
Mobil-izm DNS 10.86.16.134 3268 DOWN
Mobil-kipr centrify 10.86.16.139 464 DOWN
```